# Kops interaction between vpc with internal configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

My goal is deploy cluster in AWS in some private VPC(let say A) and provide peering connection with other VPC (let say B). The main idea that access to k8s should be available only from VPC B. As far as I understand for it I should create a private topology cluster with internal load balancer. Like this:

```
kops create cluster --name=$cluster --state=$state --zones=$zones --topology=private --networking=weave --api-loadbalancer-type=internal
```

But unfortunately kops put api load balancer in private subnet, so make it unreachable from other VPC. If I make it public

```
kops create cluster --name=$cluster --state=$state --zones=$zones --topology=private --networking=weave --api-loadbalancer-type=public
```

Kops create a internet visible api load balancer and I want to avoid this for secure. Have anyone know is it possible to implement such solution via kops?

Comment: When you say access to k8s do you mean access to the services running within k8s or access to the k8s api server for cluster management? API server access can be limited via the `--admin-access` flag this will restrict API access to a provided CIDR.  If not set, access will not be restricted by IP. (default [0.0.0.0/0])

Comment: @Clowin I mean access to k8s api for cluster management. I don't set ```--admin-access``` flag so in my case it no restricted [0.0.0.0/0]

Comment: Okay then setting the --admin-access flag should solve your problems right? I'll add that as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The load balancer directs traffic to the pods you are running inside the cluster. So if the pods need to be exposed to external traffic what you are doing works.

If you want to restrict access to the cluster api which is used for cluster management please use the `--admin-access` flag this will restrict API access to a provided CIDR. If not set, access will not be restricted by IP. (default [0.0.0.0/0])

Comment: I already try it. I set up --api-loadbalancer-type=public and use --admin-access=172.20.0.0/16 but it didn't work as well. As I realized AWS create a public api for access to load balancer and communication will be like VPC B -> internet -> VPC A, but there are also restriction on VPC B side to access a public internet I would like to communication like VPC B->VPC A

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the private subnet that the loadbalancer is put in in your first example should really be an issue and I would use that over the public one if you want security.

At a guess this is more an issue with the VPC Peering and routing not being correct rather than with the kops setup

Are the two VPCs on different subnets and are the route tables correctly routing the traffic?